# How to get the width of ‘browser content width’ in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, viewport

[image]

How to get the width of this area in google chrome? (notice:I'm opening a devtool dock in right)

I tried use window.innerWidth, but as the zoom sacle(command + / command -)changes,   window.innerWidth changes, if zoom is not 100%, I can't get the number I want

Comment: `innerWidth * devicePixelRatio`

Comment: thank you!  Is there a way to know, what's the inital dpr of current device? in macos is 2 so i need use innerWidth * devicePixelRatio/2

Comment: What units are you wanting the width in? CSS pixels or device pixels or...